# Can't find specific characters written in Input string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**What I'm trying to do**

The app I'm building is a list of tasks, displayed in `input` text fields.

Some tasks will have a day/month - written as day/month digits.

When the app is refreshed, it calls the function `callBackTime()` which identifies which rows have a day/month set and then will do something with that data.

**The plan**

The function first scans through all the `input` fields, looking for `/` and, if found, will figure out the day and month written. Currently, all I need for it to do is output those values in the console, but I can't get that far.

**My code**

Here is the code for the function (heavily commented):

```
function callBackTime(){

    //for each input
    $('div#rows>div.column>div.row>div.input-group>input.row-name').each(function(){
        var searchResult = $(this).val().toString(); //value of this input
        //if '/' is found ...
        if(searchResult.indexOf('/') >= 0) {

            //separate string to individual words
            var words = searchResult.split(' '); 

            words.each(function(){ //for each word...
                if(searchResult.indexOf('/')>=0){ //find the word that contains '/'
                    var dayMon = words.split('/'); //separate into day and month values
                    var day = dayMon[0]; //first in array is day (we're not American)
                    var mon = dayMon[1]; //second in array month
                    console.log(day+' of '+mon); //log the data
                }
            });
        }
    })
}
```

A sample row could look like so:

```
<div class="container" id="rows">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <div class="row" data-id="35" data-wr_replaced="true">
            <div class="input-group" data-wr_replaced="true">
                <div class="input-group-btn" data-wr_replaced="true">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default task-delete" 
                            data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal-delete" 
                            onclick="deleteRow(1,35)" data-wr_replaced="true">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control row-name" 
                       value="Balmforth Associates - Bryony 12/5 (ad on Reed)">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('div#rows>div.column>div.row>div.input-group>input.row-name').each` :O holy mother of god

Comment: Yes, the selector is long but it works. Still getting to grips with nesting in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You again check the `searchResult` for the `/` character when iterating over the words. I think what you meant is this:

```
//separate string to individual words
var $words = $(searchResult.split(' '));

$words.each(function (index, word){ //for each word...
    if (word.indexOf('/') >= 0){ //find the word that contains '/'
        var dayMon = word.split('/'); //separate into day and month values
        var day = dayMon[0]; //first in array is day (we're not American)
        var mon = dayMon[1]; //second in array month
        console.log(day + ' of ' + mon); //log the data
    }
});
```

Comment: The console is saying `Uncaught TypeError: words.each is not a function`

Comment: And now `Uncaught TypeError: word.indexOf is not a function`?

Comment: Again check edited answer :) first parameter of the callback is the index